# Passing alias as parameter

Tags: bash, shell, unix, alias

I am using bash shell in Unix and within bash profile [`.bashrc`] I have created few aliases to navigate to different directories.
My requirement is to pass that alias name as parameter to a function and use alias to navigate to that directory inside the function.

So I have following things inside `.bashrc`:

```
alias nav='cd /app/nav/'

function test(){
    $1;
}
```

Now I run this command `test nav` but the alias doesn't work inside the function.
Any suggestions on how to get this going?

Comment: Investigate CDPATH; make sure you set it so that the first directory is the current directory `CDPATH=:/app`.  Now you can just type `cd nav` and it will take you to `/app/nav` unless you happen to have a sub-directory `nav` in the current directory.  When it uses `CDPATH`, the shell tells you which directory it changed to.

Comment: If you used functions instead of aliases, then you would have no problem passing them as arguments. It's just as easy: `nav() { cd /app/nav; }` (one character shorter, in fact).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need the dangerous `eval`--dangerous because it might do something that unexpected such as:

```
test "rm -fr /"
```

Also, please do not call your function `test`, which is a reserved word. Here is my solution:

```
function doalias() {
    if alias $1 2> /dev/null; then
        eval $1
    fi
}
```

Now, you can invoke it as:

```
doalias nav
```

## Discussion

- Your function might simply be `eval $1` and be done with it, but I added a safeguard to test the first parameter to see if it is an alias and only call `eval` upon true.
- I don't want the output of the `alias` command, so I hid it by mean of `2> /dev/null`

Comment: Didn't know much about aliases, and it seems eval could invoke it. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you declare them as functions instead:

```
function nav {
    cd /app/nav
}

function test {
    echo "Testing function $*."  ## Optional message.
    "$@"
}
```

Example run:

```
> test nav
Testing function nav.
bash: cd: /app/nav: No such file or directory
```

It's an error, but it shows that nav is executed inside test function.

Also I suggest using a different name besides `test` since `test` itself is a builtin. See `help test`.

Comment: In my case, function nav {..} results in: "-bash: /etc/.bash_aliases: Zeile 10: Syntaxfehler beim unerwarteten Wort »}«"
Whereas with function nav(){..} it works. First line of the file is "#!/bin/bash" .Any help?

Comment: @Timo Was there any other difference between the two functions besides `()`? Perhaps place them on `pastebin.com`? Also, consider the shell you're using to execute it. Make sure it's bash and check the version as well.